# Unable to connect docker container to logstash via gelf driver

Tags: docker, logstash, docker-compose, elastic-stack, gelf

Hi guys i'm having trouble to send my server container logs to my ELK stack. No input is sent to logstash so i'm unable to set kibana index for collecting logs. I think my problem is in the port settings.

Here is the docker-compose yml for the LAMP stack (only the server service):

```
version: '3'

services:
  server:
    build: ./docker/apache
    links:
      - fpm
    ports:
      - 80:80 # HTTP
      - 443:443 # HTTPS
    logging:
      driver: "gelf"
      options:
        gelf-address: "udp://127.0.0.1:5000"
        tag: "server"
```

And here is the docker-compose yml for the ELK stack, based on [deviantony/docker-elk github project](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk)

```
version: '2'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    build: elasticsearch/
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    build: logstash/
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build: kibana/
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/:/usr/share/kibana/config
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:

  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the mistake, i've to specify the UDP protocol in the logstash service port definition.

```
logstash:
  build: logstash/
  volumes:
    - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
    - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  ports:
    - "5000:5000/udp"
  environment:
    LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
  networks:
    - elk
  depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the gelf input plugin. Here an example of a functioning compose file:

```
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.3.1
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
    networks:
      - logging
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:12201:12201/udp"
    entrypoint: logstash -e 'input { gelf { } } output { stdout{ } }'
```

You can test it by running:

```
docker run --log-driver=gelf --log-opt gelf-address=udp://127.0.0.1:12201 ubuntu /bin/sh -c 'while true; do date "+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%3N"; sleep 1 ; done
```

and checking docker logs on the logstash container.

Comment: Of course i'm using this pipeline config `input {
  gelf {
    port => 5000
    type => docker
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
  }
}
` But isn't working

Comment: try to output to stdout instead of elastic so you are sure the problem is not between logstash and elastic but on logstash not receiving anything. The config I told you worked for me so you could use it to find out where your configuration problems are. What do the logs of logstash say?